# Variable de un JSON undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json

buenas a todos, de neuvo, el tema JSON em resulta algo Troll ya que es facil tratar con los datosd e esta manera pero no entiendo en este caso la razon del por que no funciona, tengo este codigo JavaScript (aun no esta completo)

```
function ver_bookmark(id_sub_categoria){

    console.log(id_sub_categoria);

    if( $("#add").length > 0 ) {

        $.post('.show_bookmarks.php',{id_sub_categoria:id_sub_categoria},
            function(response){
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(response);

                for(var i in response){
//hago un console.log(response[i]) y lo hace 
//bien pero cuando le aññado en este caso que me muestre el id o algun otro dato
// es donde falla
                    console.log(response[i].id);
                    $('#add').html(
                        $('<div/>',{'id':'my_card','class':'col s12 m6'}).append(
                            $('<div/>',{'class':'card'}).append(
                                $('<div/>',{'class':'card-image'}).append(
                                    $('<img/>',{'src':'ficheros/bookmark/'+response[i].fichero})
                                )
                            )));
                }

            });
    }else{
        console.log("no existe");
    }
}
```

los datos en el archivo PHP estan aqui

```
$lista_bookmark =lista_bookmark('',$conn);
$lista_book = [];

for ($i=0; $i < $lista_bookmark['count']; $i++) { 
    if ($_POST['id_sub_categoria'] == $lista_bookmark[$i]['id_book_subcategoria']) {
        $lista_book = array(
            'id' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['id'],
            'id_book_subcategoria'=> $lista_bookmark[$i]['id_book_subcategoria'],
            'url'=> $lista_bookmark[$i]['url'],
            'titulo' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['titulo'],
            'usuario' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['usuario'],
            'password' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['password'],
            'notas' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['notas'],
            'fichero' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['fichero'],
            'favorito' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['favorito']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($lista_book, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

en el codigo javaScript cuando pongo que muestre lo que recoge del archivo .PHP lo hace bien, hago en `console.log(respose)` cuando ya esta pasado a formato JSON y lo hace bien, alguien sabria cual es mi error?, no es la primera vez que trabajo con esto, de hecho ya tengo varias dudas resueltas en este medio, fijo que será alguna tonteria ya lo siento pero no lo veo por que cuando hago que me imprima `response[i]<cualquier parametro>` aparece como undefined.
un saludo.
y gracias por la atencion :) les dejo imagenes de lo que muestra con exactitud.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esa última imagen es un console.log de `response` o de `response[i]`?

Comment: es la del response @Dibort

Comment: tu intención es que tu `$lista_book` tenga X posiciones o solo 1 cuando lo encuentre con ese if?

Comment: en lugar de . para acceder a elementos del objeto usa ->

Comment: @JLM `->`con javascript?

Comment: me he ido a php! perdón :-D @Dibort

Comment: mi intencion es listar todos los elementos  de `$lista_bookmark` con un for a partir de ahi si `$_POST` coincide con el `$lista_bookmark[$i]['id_book_subcategoria']` guarda los elementos que yo le digo en un array que en este caso es `$lista_book`, una vez haya hecho eso todo lo que haya recogido lo pasa a JSON y de ahi lo paso al codigo Jquery para ser tratado

Comment: @JLM con el **.** da la mismo, debido a que solo me lista un elemento de mi base de datos, acabo de crear un elemento mas, y me lista el ultimo creado lo que no esta funcionando bien el el codigo PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según comentas, tu intención es tener X listas en la variable `$lista_book`, actualmente estás machacando siempre su valor en cada iteración de tu `for` en caso de que entre en el `if`.

Deberías cambiar la asignación del array `$lista_book = array(` a `$lista_book[] = array(` en tu PHP, si no siempre tienes solo 1 posición en tu array y por eso tu for de javascript no te funciona como quieres, ya que estás recorriendo las posiciones del array (id, id_book_subcategoria...) en vez de cada lista entera.

```
$lista_bookmark =lista_bookmark('',$conn);
$lista_book = [];

for ($i=0; $i < $lista_bookmark['count']; $i++) { 
    if ($_POST['id_sub_categoria'] == $lista_bookmark[$i]['id_book_subcategoria']) {
        $lista_book[] = array( // Así generarás X arrays en tu $lista_book
            'id' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['id'],
            'id_book_subcategoria'=> $lista_bookmark[$i]['id_book_subcategoria'],
            'url'=> $lista_bookmark[$i]['url'],
            'titulo' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['titulo'],
            'usuario' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['usuario'],
            'password' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['password'],
            'notas' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['notas'],
            'fichero' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['fichero'],
            'favorito' => $lista_bookmark[$i]['favorito']);
    }
}
echo json_encode($lista_book, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: Lo dicho era un tonteria jaja! Gracias! claro cahcaba el array no poniendole los cochertes y tomaba como variable madre mia, jaja me hace gracia :) y de nuevo muchas gracias!!!